# How to mock rest controller with ResponseEntity as return object?

Tags: spring-mvc, spock, spring-mvc-test

Im making a unit test in a rest controller and this is the return:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(result);
```

Im getting this error:

```
Required request body is missing
```

This is my current test:

```
def "Signup"() {
        given:
            UserDto userDto = new UserDto(id: 1, password: "password123",   username: "username123")
            def personDto = new PersonDto(id: 1, user : userDto)
        when: "signup url is hit"
            def response = mockMvc.perform(post('/person/signup'))
        then:
            personService.signup(userDto) >> personDto
            response.andExpect(status().isOk())
    }
```

Any idea how to mock .body or how to add a body in the request. Thanks ::)

Answer (score 0):

Add another expectation like:

```
response.andExpect(content().string(containsString('blah')))
```

Reference:

[`MockMvcResultMatchers.content()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#content--)

[`ContentResultMatchers.string(org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super String> matcher)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ContentResultMatchers.html#string-org.hamcrest.Matcher-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC


def accountId = "yourAccountId" // this is the number after http://basecamp.com when logged into the basecamp website e.g. http://basecamp.com/1234567
def userName = "basecampUserName"
def password = "basecampPassword"

def basecamp = new RESTClient( "https://basecamp.com/${accountId}/api/v1/".toString() )
basecamp.auth.basic userName, password

def response = basecamp.get(
                   path: "projects.json",
                   headers: ["User-Agent": "My basecamp application (myemail@domain.com)"]
                )
println response.data.toString(2) // or you can return this value and do whatever you want
```

---

// post with body

```
def 'test post method'(){
 given:
 restClient .headers.Accept = 'application/json'

 when:
 def resp = restClient .post(path: 'path(ex:/api/list/',
 query:[param1:'param1value',param2:'param2value'],
 body: 'your json',
 contentType:'application/json'
 )

 then:
 resp.status == 200

 }
}
```